# jQuery each function not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I have this below code that works on initial page load but after the ajax call, it is not working.

```
 $.each($(document).find("[data-type='datepicker']"), (function (index, element) {
     $(element).datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'dd M yy'
     });
 }));
```

How to use event handler with .each function?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Where is your ajax call and how does it fit in with this code? `.each` isn't live. If you change the collection, you'll need to run it again.

Comment: Please show the code from your ajax call.  I'm guessing that the problem is  the relation between that code and the code you've shown.

Comment: invest 20 minutes in learning debugging javascript-code (http://getfirebug.com/javascript).

Comment: I assume that this piece of code isn't inside just `document.ready`, but also inside `ajax success`! If it is not inside `ajax success`  then this ain't gonna work dear..  because `ajax` doesn't refresh the page and `document.ready` will not be called again..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$.each` just use your datepicker selector like,

```
$("[data-type='datepicker']").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd M yy'
});
```